# Where do I put the dll when I've compiled a httphandler into a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a httphandler that I got from msdn, looks this way

```
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public HelloWorldHandler()
    {
    }
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
        // This handler is called whenever a file ending 
        // in .sample is requested. A file with that extension
        // does not need to exist.
        Response.Write("hello"); 


    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

So I compiled it to `Handler.dll` and put it in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Handler`

I then added this Web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.abc" 
        type="HelloWorldHandler", "HelloWorldHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and put it in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Handler` also

[image]

I thought with this then I could go to `http://localhost/Handler/page.abc` and the handler would intercept the request, but this doesn't go this way? I suspect it is maybe the .config file? Please help.

[image]

Comment: put it in a `bin` folder

Comment: hmmmm no that didn't do anything. do i need to include the code file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is not proper, you need to add the namespace of the class to the type and also declare the handler dll, change the `type` node;

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>        
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.abc" name="HelloWorldHandler"
        type="HelloWorldHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is inaccurate. Namespace is not required if the class does not have a namespace. According to the code in the question, it does not.

Comment: yeah it does not have a namespace

Comment: Uncommon? Yes. Strange? Hardly =)

Comment: @zespri I do believe not having a namespace is totally against best practices. Can you find a case where not using namespaces will be beneficial?

Comment: @zespri please do not advice anything, that will have no use at all:)

Comment: @HitherePaperbag then you need to put it into <handlers>; not <httphandlers>; I have updated the answer.

Comment: i got it now, don't know what it was to be honest.